# Pure JS Character Counter - Why is my code Ignoring maxLength setting?

Tags: javascript, html

A while back I put together a pure js code snippet to count off the available characters left in an `<textarea>`. (Massive thanks to SE for the assistance there.) I now need something similar but for inputs, so I set about tweaking my code slightly. All appears to be working well except for my maxLength Variable, and to be honest I have no idea why.

> I set the maxLength using the code below but it appears to be ignoring
>   it completely.

```
// input attributes... 
document.getElementsByName('ptitle')[0].placeholder = 'Your Title Here...'; 
document.getElementsByName('ptitle')[0].maxLength = '28';
```

If someone could point out my rookie mistakes publicly I would be thankful. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/cooc0b3v/28/) included.

---

> EDIT : **Added setAttribute, via @Sanchit Patiyal's suggestion. See Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/cooc0b3v/53/).**

Comment: Your JS Fiddle is working for me in Chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: Funny you should say that, I'm using chrome too.

Comment: I don't know where is your error, in my test the maxLength was working perfect :/

Comment: The problem was with line 3 in the Jsfiddle. Not sure why it was working on your side. I had to amend to setAttribute to get the input restriction working on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) for this

```js
document.getElementById('text_input').setAttribute('maxlength',5);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text_input"/>
```

Comment: You legend. Completely forgot about setAttribute.

Comment: @Beaniie Glad I helped :)